# Display Article parameters using PHP and MYSQL by their ID

Tags: php, mysql, blogs

I am new to mysql and php and I am struggling with this issue. I am bulding a "blog-like" website just to learn the languages, and I came across this problem.

I want to display articles on the homepage, relevant to their "age". This means, the biggest slider should show the latest article, and two small articles below this should be the second and third latest article.

I would do it by ID but I am really stuck somewhere in the middle. I made this prototype code which works like I want, but I am 100% sure there is a simplier way + If I would like to spread 10 latest articles across the whole homepage, that would be just crazy to create each variable for each article.

I am open to any suggestions but please note, that I am still noob in PHP & MYSQL. Thank You.

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
$sql1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$sql2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1");
$sql3 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,2");
$latestarticle = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
$secondlatestarticle = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
$thirdlatestarticle = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3);
?>
```

and this is the HTML part

```
<!--First Big Slide-->
<a href="#"><?=htmlspecialchars($firstlatestarticle['name'])?></a>
<!--Small Article below-->
<a href="#"><?=htmlspecialchars($secondlatestarticle['name'])?></a>
<!--Another Small Article below-->
<a href="#"><?=htmlspecialchars($thirdlatestarticle['name'])?></a>
```

Comment: Read about `foreach` loops

Comment: Hey, I read about while and foreach loops before placing this question, but I did not find that quite useful for this issue. Maybe it is, I read some basic stuff on w3schools only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much on the right track here, but the implementation is a bit off.

```
if($result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3") != false){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $articles[] = $row;
    }
}

echo $articles[0]['name'];
echo $articles[1]['name'];
echo $articles[2]['name'];
```

While you attempt to sort on id, which is ofcourse the latest added to the table it should actually be done with sorting by the date when the article was added. However it still works as you want it so its fine.

But the real optimization is in your 3 separate query's to the database as in my example it is just 1.

Comment: OMG thank you so much. It actually works like I want :) I would've never thought of this trick with the array. Thank you :)

Comment: could you just please tell me why it does not work with the [] after $articles. I assume this is a multidimensional array (array made from mysqli query is put into array called articles) right? But I can not find anything with the "[ ]" in syntax of arrays when defining them. Applying yes, but never defining. I hope you understand what I am asking :) thanks

Comment: Assigning a value to an array with no key `[]` uses the next free available numeric index of the array. Debug the array with `print_r($arr)` or `var_dump($arr)`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: (untested)

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
 {
     echo '<a href="#">'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).'</a>';
 }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. But wouldn't this just show a list of 10 latest articles? I need to place each name to a different part of the website. Correct me if Im wrong pls.

Comment: If the tags come right after each other, you can use a counter in the loop, to see if it's the first article (then make it big). You can also just push the results to an array, then you can check how many elements the array contains, and do whatever you want with each element. Let me know if you need another example of that.